# 3 Paired Datasets Hypothesis testing

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, paired-data

n = 72 subjects were randomised to 3 treatment groups: A, B, C, such that n = 26 for Group A, n = 29 for Group B, n = 17 for Group C. Measurements were taken before and after treatmentThe differences were calculated between the before & after-treatment observations for the 3 treatment groups: A_diff, B_diff, C_diff. Shapiro test p-value for A_diff = 0.2567, Shapiro test p-value for B_diff = 0.007945, Shapiro test p-value for C_diff = 0.5156. What hypothesis test would I use? One-way ANOVA? Kruskal-Wallis's Test? Suggestions for post-hoc tests?

Comment: one-way ANOVA is robust enough against non-normality at sample size n = 72.  tukey kramer test if variances are homoscedastic.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: This isn't my homework, but thank you!